# SQL Server - Using GO for multiple statements in prepared statement

Tags: sql-server, prepared-statement

I have been trying to execute a prepared statement using SQL Server that has 2 sql statements, one to create table, and one to update the default value for the `created` column.

I've basically copied the create code from MSSMS and stringified it.

This is my SQL (`@name` is the database name to be created)

```
declare @q varchar(max);
set @q=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@name,' (',
'[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,',
'[created] [datetime] NULL,',
'CONSTRAINT [PK_',@name,'] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED',
'(',
'[id] ASC',
')WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]',
') ON [PRIMARY];',
'GO;',
'ALTER TABLE ',@name,' ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_',@name,'_created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created];',
'GO;');
exec(@q);
```

It's telling me I have incorrect syntax around the `GO` statements, despite have statement break semi-colons.

Is having 2 statements inside a prepared statement even possible in this context?

Should I wrap them in some other fashion?

*BTW: Put `GO` in any google search and you get a thousand results for some GoSQL language I never heard of.*

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL command (`GO` is used in SQL Server Management Studio), so remove it from the statement.

Comment: [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) is **not** a T-SQL keyword, it is interpreted by the IDE as a batch separator. From the linked documentation: *"GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor."* Also, that statement is dangerously open to Injection.

Comment: Narrow your Google search to "T-SQL GO" and the relevant answers will be on the first page.

Comment: Removing the `GO` statements fixed the issue, I thought they were needed to ensure correct flow (like *do this until its done...* then *do this*). This function will never be exposed to anyone, it's just a cheat for me to create tables based on a template. I know it's dangerous, but nobody else will ever be able to use it.

Comment: `GO` is never needed for flow (T-SQL is strictly sequential) but it's often necessary because not all DDL statements work correctly if they're not separated into their own batches (as compilation may fail due to objects not being available). You are "lucky" here in that your sequence of statements happens to work in a single batch. You can always use multiple `EXEC`s, which is roughly the same (not precisely, but the details are finicky and you'll run into it when you run into it).

Comment: @JeroenMostert So I guess the question should of been *How to batch statements in a prepared statement?*

Comment: You can't run multiple batches in a single prepared statement, Mike. As @JeroenMostert  aludes to, though, you can use things like `sys.sp_executesql` to defer the validation of the statement, and also have it run in it's own scope. This isn't the same as running inside a separate batch, however, it achieves very similar results.